# Declaring and allocating to a 2D char pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

how do I declare and allocate a 2-D array without knowing beforehand how many characters per string (char array) are going to be there?
For instance, this-

```
char** input = new char*(m*sizeof(char*)) //where m is input from terminal
```

gives error-

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘long unsigned int’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
```

Building on that, I have a function which takes a char** as an argument. I want to know how many char arrays are stored through this pointer.

```
int read2DArray(char* arr[]){
int l=0;
while(arr[l][0]!='\0') l++;
return l;
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Did you try it? What's the result?

Comment: Thats the problem, I couldn't try it without declaring it correctly first.

Comment: `char** input = new char*[m*sizeof(char*)]`

Comment: @AntonSavin: That's probably a larger array than the OP intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct only if the being that made the 2D array was considerate enough to terminate it with a 1D array of length 1, containing the single character '\0'.

You can use that convention if you like. An alternative is to pass the dimensions of the array as additional arguments.

As for declaring the array, use brackets not parentheses, and don't mention sizeof(anything)-- the compiler will take care of the sizes.

```
char** input = new char*[m];
```

You got the error message because you were telling the compiler to create a new `char*` with the *value* m*sizeof(char *).

Comment: I can't pass the size arguments, since I have to write a function for an already written driver program (like Topcoder). What is the general way to check then? strlen()? But that also takes '\0' as a terminator.

Comment: @goelakash: in that case you must consult the documentation of the program to see what its convention is-- or examine the code to see how it constructs the array. At a guess, I'd expect it to terminate the char* array with a char* that is NULL, and each char array with a char that is '\0'.